# Andriod Studio Button color not changing

Tags: xml, android-studio, button

In my android application I want one of the buttons' corner to be rounded and its color to be different than the default. I created an xml file that would achieve this. After setting this xml file as the background of my button the shape has changed but the color stayed the default. I tried setting this xml file as the background of a TextView and it worked fine with that.
The button_shape.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="#03A9F4" />
</shape>
```

The Button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btRandom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
    android:text="MyButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle" />
```

Comment: Hello, you can try changing the tint of the button to #03A9F4

Comment: I have already tried it but if the background is set to that xml file the color does not change even if I change the tint.

Comment: You can try creating a button style with that background and tint and applying it to this button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar` with `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar`  under folders res--> values--> themes --> themes.xml. In android studio 4.1, by default a theme is already applied on Buttons. Then you can simply say: `android:background="@color/black"` for example.